# WinTV USB doesn't show up as a video capture device when calling capGetDriverDescriptionA VB.net 2012

Tags: vb.net, webcam, video-capture

I have successfully got a live video window from a Creative VF0350 webcam.

However if I remove the webcam and plug in a Hauppauge WinTv usb 7, the Creative webcam still shows up as a capture device, even after a reboot. No sign of the WinTv device either.

I'm calling capGetDriverDescriptionA to get a list of capture devices (in the avicap32.dll).

Is this a wintv driver problem?

Comment: You are using deprecated API, use a newer one which does better job identifying the camera devices.

Comment: I'm only going by a webcam example on MSDN... admittedly it's 2011, so ancient in MS terms... I'll have a play with DirectShow instead...

Comment: `capGetDriverDescriptionA` is still here, but it's been deprecated for 10+ years, even if sample is included into recent SDK. Not to mention that it supports only a subset of video sources.